# Another dice error, code not quite working

Tags: javascript, probability, dice

Line 6 says it's expecting an identifier.
I'm trying to make it so rolling a 1 on either die makes the score 0, and rolling doubles doubles your score, otherwise, the score is the sum of the two die.

```
var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 1);
var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 1);
var score;
if(die1 === 1 || die2 === 1){
    score = 0;
else {
    score = die1 + die2;
}
  if(die1 === die2)
    score = 2*(die1 +die2);
  else{
    score = die1 + die2;
}
}
console.log("You rolled a "+die1+" and a "+die2+" for a score of "+score);
```

Comment: Check your opening and closing braces.

Comment: Reformatting code really helps find strange problems.  If your editor doesn't have a good reformatter, go to http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1):

You never closed the bracket before the "else".

Change

```
if(die1 === 1 || die2 === 1){
    score = 0;
else {
    score = die1 + die2;
}
```

to be

```
if(die1 === 1 || die2 === 1){
    score = 0;
} else {
    score = die1 + die2;
}
```

Comment: I think I'm supposed to be nesting the codes though

Comment: actually with a little reformatting it worked out after all, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code properly formatted and with the `if` statements cleaned:

```
var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
var score;

if (die1 === 1 || die2 === 1)
    score = 0;
else if (die1 === die2)
    score = 2 * (die1 + die2);
else
    score = die1 + die2;

console.log("You rolled a " + die1 + " and a " + die2 + " for a score of " + score);
```